# Extension updateserver / update not working

Tags: extension-update

I'm trying to make this update server work, I've exhausted all option available to me. Here is what I've checked / done so far:

updateserver file is located in the server and accessible (extension.xml)
downloadurl / extension file is also available and accessible (mod_my_module.zip)

I've checked in the database tables - it uses correct url for the updateservers

"targetplatform" is set and in order

I've cleared the cache and checked for update, my extension is not getting listed.

What else can I check or do?

this is the updateserver code:

```
<updates>
    <update>
        <name>Nice Social Bookmark</name>
        <description>Nice Social Bookmark 3.5.1 - Joomla 3.x module for displaying links to most common social sites.</description>
        <element>joomla</element>
        <type>module</type>
        <client>0</client>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <infourl title="Salamander Studios">https://www.salamander-studios.com/</infourl>
        <downloads>
            <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">https://www.salamander-studios.com/download/download-nice-social-bookmark-free?download=6:nice-social-bookmark-3-5-1</downloadurl>
        </downloads>
        <tags>
            <tag>stable</tag>
            <tag>free</tag>
        </tags>
        <maintainer>Nikola Biskup</maintainer>
        <maintainerurl>https://www.salamander-studios.com</maintainerurl>
        <section>Social Multishare</section>
        <targetplatform name="joomla" version=".*"/>
    </update>
</updates>
```

and this is from extension file itself:

```
<updateservers>
    <server type="extension" priority="2" name="Nice Social Bookmark Updates">https://www.salamander-studios.com/updateserver/nsb-free.xml</server>
</updateservers>
```

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Please post the code you have in the XML file on your server and your extension so we can see if there are any visible issues.

Comment: thank you, I've updated the question with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that stands out after seeing your code is the following:

```
<element>joomla</element>
```

which is incorrect. The `element` tag should contain the untranslated extension name i.e. `mod_custom`

Also, you're using `<tag>free</tag>` which is also incorrect. The accepted values for the `<tag>` element are:

- dev
- alpha
- beta
- rc
- stable

**Note:** If you provide more than one tag containing one of the aforementioned stability keywords only the LAST tag will be taken into account. If you do not provide any tags Joomla! will assume it is a stable version.

Hope this helps

Comment: yes, it was the <element> tag that was causing the problem, thank you for your insights